# SQL: Calculate the number of days from overlapping date range

Tags: sql, overlapping, days

I want to count the number of days for each ID but the days are overlapping.

```
ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE
1   19/12/2012  29/01/2013
1   30/05/2013  14/07/2013
1   15/02/2013  12/03/2013
1   13/03/2013  18/03/2013
1   19/03/2013  26/03/2013
1   27/01/2013  07/04/2013
1   08/04/2013  09/04/2013
2   08/04/2013  14/07/2013
2   30/05/2013  12/07/2013
3   08/04/2013  10/04/2013
3   23/05/2013  30/06/2013
```

Comment: Please provide a clear example of what you would expect to see as a result.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? This site is for problem solving, not for ready copy-paste solutions from scratch.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more?  Why can't you just use `DateDiff()`?

Comment: By your explanation it seems the you do not want to recount overlapping days. So do you want to merge two or more overlapping date ranges into one and then take a date difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF( d,STARTDATE,ENDDATE)) AS [Days],ID
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

OR TO GET THE NUMBER OF DAYS FROM THE MIN/MAX DATE RANGE:

```
SELECT D.ID, SUM(DATEDIFF( d,D.STARTDATE,D.ENDDATE)) AS [Days]
FROM (
SELECT ID, MIN(STARTDATE) AS [STARTDATE], MAX(ENDDATE) AS [ENDATE]
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID , MIN(STARTDATE), MAX(ENDDATE) 
) AS D
ORDER BY D.ID
```